# Can we merge [importlib] with [python-importlib]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[importlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importlib) and [python-importlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-importlib)

At the time of writing this post, the former tag has 16 questions and the latter has 237. Looking at all 16 questions tagged [importlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importlib), they're all about the Python stock module `importlib`, so it makes total sense to merge and synonymize them.